# How to make Google Sheet AppScript code to copy Input Table data to a 'Master Data' table in a different sheet?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am trying to copy data from range 'Table1' in an Input sheet to the last empty row at the end of range 'Table2' in the Master Data sheet automatically when a function is run.

So far the intended function is to:

1. User inputting their input values within range 'Table1' (note: range is previously manually set as the whole table excluding header rows) in the Input sheet, then the "importData" function will be run.
2. The function to read values within range 'Table1' and filter any empty rows or incomplete rows.
3. The function to copy the filtered values (which may contain 1-50 rows of data) and paste the values to the last empty row within range 'Table2' (note: range is previously manually set as the whole table excluding header rows) in the Master Data sheet. Note that Table2 may have blank rows in between existing data so the function need to find the last empty row from the bottom of the range Table2.
4. The function to add more rows within the end of the range 'Table2' in case the current range is not enough to fill the data from 'Table1'.
5. The function to clear values within the original range 'Table1' in the Input sheet.

I am trying to find a solution where only the Named Range 'Table1' and 'Table2' is referenced so that it will still work even if the sheet order or sheet name is changed.

Here is a spreadsheet to illustrate the sheets and ranges mentioned above: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rEytxFeBhh3AcynSk4rrlvRJ-QIY9Au4O9x4_p93kM4/edit?usp=sharing

So far here is what I got for function #1-3:

```
function importData() {

var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('Table1'); //Table1 is the Named Range of the Input Table

//removing the empty rows below

var range1 = range.getValues();

  const rangeFiltered = range1.filter(function (x) {
    return !(x.every(element => element === (undefined || null || ''))) });
  

if (rangeFiltered != null) {
  Logger.log(rangeFiltered);}

}
```

Any help or pointers on this would be appreciated. Thank you!